# Sharepoint 2010 Timer Job Custom Properties

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, custom-properties, sharepoint-timer-job

I am converting a WSS3 Timer Job to SP 2010 and having problems with Custom Properties.
In WSS3 i had to download an deploy a Timer Job Manager which sat in Sharepoint Administration and allowed me to manage the date and time of when jobs were run as well as my own custom properties that i had defined in the code of my project using:

```
  <Persisted()> _
Public SiteURL As String
```

This was all i had to do and once i deployed my timer job, the custom property appeared in the timer job manager in sharepoint administration where i was then able to set it.

In SP2010 they seem to have gone half the way with Timer Jobs. They have allowed the setting of when a job runs which is exactly the same as the custom project i downloaded for WSS3 but none of the custom properties seem to be available to set.

My question is there something i am doing wrong? or have they just not incorporated this functionallity in to SP2010?

Thanks in advance for any answers, i hope ihave explained myself clearly.